# How to write a proper promise for a Firebase function that queries an external API with Axios, and saves JSON response in multiple Firestore Documents

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, axios

I would be glad if I can get some help with my first question. I am an Android developer and I am currently doing a project which requires Firebase cloud functions, which I am new to.
I am calling an external API with Axios, and saving the JSON response into multiple Firestore documents. 4 out of 5 times that I call the function, it executes without error, but it does not write to Firestore, and the 1 time it writes to Firestore, it takes as long as 8 to 12 seconds to write the data.

I read something about promises and I applied to the function(to the best of my knowledge) but the problem persists. Please let an expert tell me what I am doing wrong. Below is my cloud function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require("axios");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const api_token = "---------";
const includes = "------------";
const url = "------------" + api_token + includes;

exports.liveScores = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            var data  = response.data.data;

            data.forEach(function(obj){
                admin.firestore().collection("fixtures").doc(obj.id.toString()).set({
                id : obj.id,
                league_id : obj.league_id,
                venue : obj.venue_id,
                localteam_id : obj.localteam_id,
                visitorteam_id : obj.visitorteam_id,
                round_id : obj.round_id,
                round_name : obj.round ?  obj.round.data.name : null,
                stage_id : obj.stage_id,
                localteam_score : obj.scores.localteam_score,
                visitorteam_score : obj.scores.visitorteam_score,
                status : obj.time.status,
                timestamp : new admin.firestore.Timestamp(obj.time.starting_at.timestamp, 0),
                real_date : obj.time.starting_at.date,
                minute : obj.time.minute,
                injury_time : obj.time.injury_time,
                localteam_formation : obj.formations.localteam_formation,
                visitorteam_formation : obj.formations.visitorteam_formation,
                visitorTeam : obj.visitorTeam.data.name,
                localTeam : obj.localTeam.data.name,
                local_team_logo : obj.localTeam.data.logo_path,
                visitor_team_logo : obj.visitorTeam.data.logo_path,
                season_id : obj.season_id,
                referee : obj.referee ? obj.referee.data.fullname : null,
                aggregate : obj.aggregate ? obj.aggregate.data.result : null,
                venue_name : obj.venue && obj.venue.data.name ? obj.venue.data.name : null,
                weather_type : obj.weather_report && obj.weather_report.type ? obj.weather_report.type : null,
                weather_icon : obj.weather_report && obj.weather_report.icon ? obj.weather_report.icon : null,
                temperature : obj.weather_report && obj.weather_report.temperature_celcius ?         obj.weather_report.temperature_celcius.temp : null
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("Fixtures table complete...");
                })
                
                var no_of_events = obj.events.data.length;
                for(var i=0; i < no_of_events; i++ ){
                    admin.firestore().collection("events").doc(obj.events.data[i].fixture_id.toString()).collection("all_events").doc(obj.events.data[i].id.toString()).set({
                        type : obj.events.data[i].type,
                        team_id : obj.events.data[i].team_id,
                        fixture_id : obj.events.data[i].fixture_id,
                        var_result : obj.events.data[i].var_result,
                        player_id : obj.events.data[i].player_id,
                        player_name : obj.events.data[i].player_name,
                        related_player_id : obj.events.data[i].related_player_id,
                        related_player_name : obj.events.data[i].related_player_name,
                        minute : obj.events.data[i].minute,
                        reason : obj.events.data[i].reason,
                        id : obj.events.data[i].id
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("Events table complete...");
                    })
                }

                for(var y=0; y < obj.lineup.data.length; y++){
                    admin.firestore().collection("lineup").doc(obj.lineup.data[y].fixture_id.toString()).collection("lineup").doc(obj.lineup.data[y].player_id.toString()).set({
                        fixture_id : obj.lineup.data[y].fixture_id,
                        team_id : obj.lineup.data[y].team_id,
                        player_id : obj.lineup.data[y].player_id,
                        player_name : obj.lineup.data[y].player_name,
                        number : obj.lineup.data[y].number,
                        position : obj.lineup.data[y].position,
                        formation_position : obj.lineup.data[y].formation_position,
                        captain : obj.lineup.data[y].captain
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("Lineup table complete...");
                    })
                }

                for(var x=0; x < obj.bench.data.length; x++){
                    admin.firestore().collection("bench").doc(obj.bench.data[x].fixture_id.toString()).collection("bench").doc(obj.bench.data[x].player_id.toString()).set({
                        fixture_id : obj.bench.data[x].fixture_id,
                        team_id : obj.bench.data[x].team_id,
                        player_id : obj.bench.data[x].player_id,
                        player_name : obj.bench.data[x].player_name,
                        number : obj.bench.data[x].number,
                        position : obj.bench.data[x].position,
                        formation_position : obj.bench.data[x].formation_position,
                        captain : obj.bench.data[x].captain
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("Bench table complete...");
                    })
                }

                for(var c=0; c < obj.stats.data.length; c++){
                    admin.firestore().collection("stats").doc(obj.stats.data[c].fixture_id.toString()).collection("all_stats").doc(obj.stats.data[c].team_id.toString()).set({
                        fixture_id : obj.stats.data[c].fixture_id,
                        team_id : obj.stats.data[c].team_id,
                        total_shots : obj.stats.data[c].shots && obj.stats.data[c].shots.total ? obj.stats.data[c].shots.total : null,
                        ongoal : obj.stats.data[c].shots && obj.stats.data[c].shots.ongoal ? obj.stats.data[c].shots.ongoal : null,
                        total_passes : obj.stats.data[c].passes && obj.stats.data[c].passes.total ? obj.stats.data[c].passes.total : null,
                        attacks : obj.stats.data[c].attacks && obj.stats.data[c].attacks.attacks ? obj.stats.data[c].attacks.attacks : null,
                        fouls : obj.stats.data[c].fouls,
                        corners : obj.stats.data[c].corners,
                        offsides : obj.stats.data[c].offsides,
                        possessiontime : obj.stats.data[c].possessiontime,
                        yellowcards : obj.stats.data[c].yellowcards,
                        redcards : obj.stats.data[c].redcards,
                        injuries : obj.stats.data[c].injuries,
                        saves : obj.stats.data[c].saves,
                        tackles : obj.stats.data[c].tackles
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("Stats table complete...");
                    })
                }

            })

            return res.status(200).json(
                console.log("successful")
            )
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })
});
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not launch all those firestore queries simultaneously, but wait for each one to complete before launching the next one.

This is easier when you make the onRequest callback function `async`:

```
exports.liveScores = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let response = await axios.get(url);
        var data = response.data.data;
        for (let obj of data) {
            await admin.firestore().collection("fixtures").doc(obj.id.toString()).set({
                id: obj.id,
                /* ... */ 
            }); 
            console.log("Fixtures table complete...");
                
            for (let eventData of obj.events.data){
                await admin.firestore().collection("events").doc(eventData.fixture_id.toString()).collection("all_events").doc(eventData.id.toString()).set({
                    type: eventData.type,
                    /* ... */
                });
            }
            console.log("Events table complete...");
        
            for (let lineupData of obj.lineup.data) {
                await admin.firestore().collection("lineup").doc(lineupData.fixture_id.toString()).collection("lineup").doc(lineupData.player_id.toString()).set({
                    fixture_id: lineupData.fixture_id,
                    /* ... */
                });
            }
            console.log("Lineup table complete...");

            /* ... etc ... */
        }
        console.log("successful");
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "successful" });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
});
```

NB: don't pass `console.log("successful")` as an argument to `.json`. You'll want to pass an object as argument.

Comment: Hi Trincot. Could you please help me clarify this part. I was trying the loops one by one and the first one (Fixtures table) executed successfully. However, for the next one (Events table), i get an error that "obj is not defined." Could it be because this particular node is an array? That is why i used an iterator initially. Thank you @trincot

Comment: Ah, I had the indentation wrong. The other loops should happen inside the first loop. Updated.